I'm trying to get my RHEL 9 server to run postfix and use MySQL as the client
I'm trying to migrate my email server from an old RHEL 6 virtual image to a new RHEL 9 server. I went through the standard install with some minor SELinux issue that have been fixed. I installed the postfix and postfix-mysql along with dovecot, amavisd, spamassassin and clam RPMs from RedHat.
Since this is a migration and not a new install I copied over the main.cf and master.cf from the origial system. While testing the new server I found that the server was not talking to the db server. In checking the logs I found this message in the maillog:
Aug  2 20:04:14 <host> postfix/smtpd[191132]: warning: connect to mysql server X.X.X.X Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: /usr/lib64/mariadb/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The ./caching_sha2_password.so file does exist so a missing file is not the issue. This means that postfix is not able to get any user information for allow access.
I think this could be one of the following:

SELinux permissions are preventing the server from using the file.
The RHEL postfix RPM has the mariadb client already installed and for some reason it's interferring with the process. If this is the case then do I have to take the SRPM and roll a new one?
I am missing an RPM though I don't know which one that may be. I currently have the following postfix RPMs installed:
postfix.x86_64  2:3.5.9-24.el9
postfix-mysql.x86_64 2:3.5.9-24.el9
postfix-perl-scripts.x86_64 2:3.5.9-24.el9
Mariadb clients can't talk to MySQL server. I seriously doubt this is the issue but it did occur to me.

There are no issue with the old server other than age of the OS it's running. I'm hoping that someone out there may have seen this before or may have some insight as to where I need to look next.

It says /usr/lib64/mariadb/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so does not exist, yet you are telling us that ./caching_sha2_password.so does. We will assume that this is a totally different file unless told otherwise, since for all we know, it could be in a different directory from where it should be.
